# Android AppWidget Listview change selected imagebutton onClick

Tags: android, android-appwidget, remoteview

I've this [homescreen widget](http://jiricadek.com/widget.PNG):

It's easy to update for example two `buttons` next to the logo from `activity`, because I have their appWidgetIds from onUpdate method from `AppWidgetProvider`, but `imagebuttons` in the list are created in `RemoteViewsFactory` class in `getViewAt()` method.

```
@Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        RemoteViews row = new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(), R.layout.list_row_widget);
        row.setTextViewText(R.id.tvDescription, items.get(position).name);

        Intent i = new Intent();
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putBoolean(TimeWidgetProvider.ACTION_WORK_START, true);
        extras.putInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        i.putExtras(extras);
        row.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.btnStartWork, i);

        return (row);
    }
```

so every of them have same id (R.id.btnStartWork), and same appWidgetId which is not the row id but the whole widget id.

I need to change imagebutton in the row which I have clicked on, but because I've only one appwidget id in Activity and its for whole widget, everytime I use:

```
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getBaseContext());
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getBaseContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
views.setImageViewResource(R.id.btnStartWork, R.drawable.button_active);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mAppWidgetId, views);
```

It changes the first imagebutton not the selected one.

I have tried to pass remoteviews row from factory, but it didn't work because when I called

```
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mAppWidgetId, row);
```

with the id of whole widget, widget was gone and only the selected row was visible. I can get the position of item in list, but it's not helpful because it's not a viewId.
I have read many tutorial including this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

But still haven't found the answer, It's my first widget. Help please.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution was quite simple, in `getViewAt()` method save the position of every `imagebutton` to `extras`:

```
extras.putInt(TimeWidgetProvider.POSITION, position);
```

then in handling method store somewhere the index of selected item

```
TimeWidgetProvider.selected = extras.getInt(TimeWidgetProvider.POSITION);
```

and after that, use this:

```
appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(mAppWidgetId, R.id.list);
```

at last again in the `getViewAt()` method change `imagebutton` on index which you have previously stored.

```
if (position == TimeWidgetProvider.selected) {
    row.setImageViewResource(R.id.btnStartWork, R.drawable.button_active);
} else {
    row.setImageViewResource(R.id.btnStartWork, R.drawable.button_inactive);
}
```

The whole list is refreshed with changed states of selected items.

Thx [Tamás Müller](https://plus.google.com/+Ji%C5%99%C3%AD%C4%8Cadek/posts/dH9wZQSgf5T) for this solution.