# Android widget: Changing item layout in ListView on notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-listview, widget

I want to update the layout of some items a in a `ListView` in an android app widget if a trigger is given. So I implemented below in `getView()` method in `RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory`.

```
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    ...
    int remoteViewId;

    if (some condition) {
        remoteViewId = R.layout.highlighted_item;
    } else {
        remoteViewId = R.layout.item;
    }

    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), remoteViewId);
```

This code works when the widget is loaded for the first time, but when updated using `notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged` the layout persists and is not changed. How can I update xml layout used for a ListView item?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373858/android-appwidget-listview-change-selected-imagebutton-onclick worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Change background

If my assumption is right and you are trying to highlight a list item by changing the background color or something similar I´d suggest to use a selector drawable instead of changing the layout programmatically:

**drawable/list_item_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item 
        android:state_activated="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_background_activated" />
    
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_background_pressed" />

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_background" />

</selector>
```

**drawable/list_item_background.xml

drawable/list_item_background_pressed.xml

drawable/list_item_background_activated.xml**

Define such a drawable for each state in the selector and replace the 'color' with an appropriate color resource.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    
    <solid android:color="color" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="color" />

</shape>
```

**Apply the list selector to the ListView in the widget´s layout:**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_item_selector" />
```

I use this for my own widget and it works perfectly.
For further information on state lists see this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

### Change entire layout

In order to change the entire layout try the following:

```
public class WidgetListProvider implements RemoteViewsFactory {

    private boolean alternateLayout = 1;

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        
        alternateLayout = alternateLayout == 1 ? 2 : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        
        final RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(_context.getPackageName(),
                alternateLayout == 1 ? R.layout.list_row : R.layout.list_row2);

        [...]
        
        return rv;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        
        return 2;
    }

    [...]    
}
```

**Important**: Note getViewTypeCount() - Because you use two different layouts, you have to return 2 here. If you return 1, a loading view will be displayed for the second layout.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I could apply your method but I was wondering if I can completely change a layout of an item for wider possibilities.

Comment: Yes you could change the entire layout, I have updated my answer with a working code snippet.

Comment: Finally! I searched all day to change the layout of my widget. Once changed it got stuck on Loading... I completely forgot that if I have multiple layouts to change the getViewTypeCount. Thank you very much!